# Python: Appeneding to a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary structured like so:

```
'valid_paths' : ['path_one', 'path_two', 'path_three']
```

I'd like to append a new path to the key of this value. I looked around for the cleanest way to do this but come up with.

```
path_four = 'path_four'

paths_to_be_added = dict['valid_paths']
paths_to_be_added.append(path_four)
dict['valid_paths'] = paths_to_be_added
```

This works fine in my test runs. I've written a unit test for it and it fails with:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

And this has me confused, when I run the code my object 'paths_to_be_added' has the attribute of a list but in testing it's a string. What's happening here?

Comment: Are you sure that is the structure of your dictionary?  It seems like it is actually: `{'valid_paths' : "['path_one', 'path_two', 'path_three']"}`, where the value is a string representation of a list.

Comment: Oh on second thought it seems you may be right. But how would .append work originally if this was a string and not a list?

Comment: It wouldn't.  `append` is only available on lists.  When you called it before, the value must have been a list and then you somehow changed it into a string.  You need to find where you did this and fix it.

Answer (score 3):

You could add that item using the following

```
dict['valid_paths'].append(path_four)
```

Comment: To make this even easier, you can make the original dictionary a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects), so if the key is absent, you'll get nice clean behavior.